# How do I contribute documentation to Juju?

Tags: documentation, juju

I've found some bugs in the [Juju Documentation](https://juju.ubuntu.com/docs/faq.html) that I'd like to fix, but the docs are in some format I've not seen before, how can I contribute?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### How to contribute text

Here are the basic steps necessary to get a change published on the website:

- [Fork the repository](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo) from [github.com/juju/docs](http://github.com/juju/docs)
- Make a local branch from your fork (and enter that branch)
- Edit the source documents
- Push your branch back to your fork on GitHub
- [Submit a Pull Request](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-pull-request)

Full documentation is here:

- https://jujucharms.com/docs/stable/contributing